# how to set disk backup in GridGain for recovery

Tags: hadoop, gridgain, imdb

Hi am just new to GridGain In-Memory database. When I load the data in GridGain cluster now after some time I have requirement to shut-down full cluster and restart it again. Then how can I recover the last data that was in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GridGain enterprise edition, then you can take advantage of the Local Recoverable Store feature which automatically persists your data to disk.

For open source edition, you would have to implement your own GridCacheStore which will be responsible for persistence.